# How can I convert .obj or .stl to .usdz without Vectary?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, usdz

Apple AR Quick Look apparently only supports `.usdz` files. Is there a way to convert an `.obj` or `.stl` to `.usdz`?

I googled this first but the most popular result was to use a free tool called *Vectary*, but when I actually tried to use it, it wasn’t free.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a USDZ file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686813/how-to-create-a-usdz-file)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With iOS 13 & Reality Kit,  Apple has released a USDZ converter that does not require Xcode; the converter is a Python based tool. I have been using it the last few days to convert various files gltf, obj files.

Download link:

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=USDPython

Example usage:

```
usdzconvert someobject.obj
```

You will want to edit paths for your environment variables.

Or double click the file which is in the top level of the folder:

```
USD.command
```

to launch a shell with the environment variables set.

And within Xcode 11, you can export SCN files to USDZ files.

It is well worth watching the WWDC 2019 video; it is just over 30 minutes:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/602/

Comment: On the usdpython and macOS Big Sur it doesn’t work with the env variable double clicking on the usd.command. I got  pxr module error and env var PaTh not set up. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using **Xcode 12** and **Xcode 11**, you can utilise the following command in `Terminal`:

```
usdzconvert ~/Desktop/file.obj
```

`usdzconvert` command is a Python script that converts `.obj`, `.gltf`, `.fbx`, `.abc`, `.usda`, `.usdc`, and `.usd` assets to `usdz`.

And if you wanna use this command in Terminal, you need to download **usdz Tools** from [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/tools/).

[image]

In case you're using **Xcode 10**, type the following command in `Terminal`:

```
xcrun usdz_converter ~/Desktop/file.obj ~/Desktop/file.usdz
```

**For further details look at [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-10-converter/50867018#50867018) and [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55544185/how-to-generate-usdz-file-again-from-zip-file/55631922#55631922)**.

Comment: Is it possible to you the Python script in Linux, is there a way to try it without having the Apple Developer account?

Comment: Hi @AlbertoTono. What for?

Comment: To run on a server and offer it as conversion service?!

Comment: Yes, you can try it without having Apple Developer's account but only for testing purpose. There's no way to distribute it.

Comment: How can I download it without an Apple developer account, on devices not iOS, I am trying on my Linux machine and I am having issues.

Comment: Download what? I don't entirely understand what you mean...

Comment: USDPython for USDZconveter.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=USDPython

Comment: Ok. If you need `usdz Tools`, `USDPython`, etc, all you need is a free Apple ID to log in into `developer.apple.com` resource. There's no need to use $99 Apple Developer Account to use this tools. Xcode 12 with preinstalled `usdzconvert tools` and Reality Composer app is also free.

Comment: I think you need to have an iOS device unfortunately.

Comment: `USDZ` is for SceneKit and RealityKit frameworks. These two can be used for macOS development. I think you don't need an iOS device in that case. Also Xcode has a macOS and iOS Simulator...

Comment: Yes, you need macOS to use it. You can’t download from a Linux machine.

Comment: With a MacOS device I am having issues in setting up the env variables. I follow your great suggestions @AndyFedoroff but still I get Error of pxr module and python bindings.

Comment: Hi @AlbertoTono! I've been using `usdz Tools` since Xcode 10 release and there's no issues (except `usdzconvert 0.63` but I wrote about it here – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018).

Comment: Did you try also on the new MacBookPro with M1 and Big Sur 11?

Comment: Not yet, but it seems it's OK. I have not seen any complaints from developers.

Comment: I keep getting the pxr module error and PATH bindings even if I set up the PATH following also your instructions and the one in the readme.

Comment: I tested with other 2 devices not M1 and it is working well for those. On the USDZ specification of Pixar they mentioned that they tested with Intel for the 64 byte alignment.

Answer (score 2):

> If you're using **Xcode**, this is the easiest solution

Open the file in Xcode, then go to File > Export... and choose the file type (`.usdz` is 'Universal Scene Description (Mobile)'):

[image: Exporting as <code>.usdz</code>]

Answer (score 1):

Apple released a tool called Reality Converter that has an interface which allows you to convert your .obj, .gltf and .usd files into .usdz

Check it out: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01132020a

Answer (score 0):

Anything you upload to sketchfab.com is automatically converted to usdz (and gltf), and Sketchfab supports more than 30 formats as an input, including obj, fbx, stl, dae, blend...

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to convert on the device (no XCode required):

```
import modelIO
import SceneKit
let asset = MDLAsset(url: objURL)
let scene = SCNScene(mdlAsset: asset)
scene.write(to: usdzURL, delegate: nil, progressHandler: nil)
```

This might not work for everyone since it did not load the materials properly. In my case, it was not a big issue to manually set the materials in RealityKit. I also do not know how it handles animations. Another poster mentioned converting to .usdc and renaming to .usdz but I could not get this to work. ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53767015/14437826))

Other ways to convert to .usdz:
https://www.marxentlabs.com/usdz-files/