# How to Convert .Obj to .USDZ 3D files

Tags: objective-c, swift, arkit, .obj, usdz

I've working with the augmented reality app, I want to convert some of the 3d model files `.obj` to `usdz` file is there any way to convert using Xcode..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to convert .obj or .stl to .usdz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57940320/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-obj-or-stl-to-usdz)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest way to convert .obj or .stl to .usdz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57940320/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-obj-or-stl-to-usdz)

Comment: @Magnas Yes that's what I want, perfectly worked thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not through Xcode directly, but Apple released a beta version of "Reality Converter" that you can find through Google, download and use.

To convert, open the app, drag the file in, and then export.